# Converting slice of structs to slice of empty interface

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I'm trying to assign a slice of structs to a slice `[]interface{}` (to pass into AppEngine's `datastore.PutMulti`. However, this is causing compilation errors as the two types are apparently incompatible:
  `cannot use type[]*MyStruct as type []interface { } in assignment`

Basically I have:

```
var src []*MyStruct
var dest []interface{}
…
dest = src  // This line fails.
```

Is there anyway to copy `src` into `dest` without copying each element one-at-a-time?

Comment: In Go, assignment (=) is different from copying (built-in function 'copy').

Comment: I discovered that the go1 beta for app engine has changed the signature for `datastore.PutMulti` so that the above does work anyway. Hurrah!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're going to have to copy one-at-a-time. There's no way around it.

If it helps to accept this, you should think about the fact that wrapping a struct in an interface really does actually wrap it at the memory level. An interface contains a pointer to the original type and a descriptor for the type itself. When casting a single struct to an interface, you're really wrapping it. So copying them one-at-a-time is necessary in order to wrap the structs up in the interface.

Comment: That is what I feared. The fact that it takes some "work" to cast in the single case explains why the compiler won't just do it for you with slices. Oh well!

Comment: Note that the reason for having to do this is a trade off between easy conversion to interfaces and indirection at the struct level.